# Word count histogram

Tags: c, histogram, codeblocks

I want to make a program that read a paragraph in a .txt file, the function needs to count the length of each word and add the number of words with same length into corresponding frequency.  For example, if the paragraph has 2 words with length of 5, then the bin frequency of bin = 2 will be 5.

However, all my bin and freq values read 0 in my output, like this:

0.0/0.0 *

0.0/0.0 *

0.0/0.0 *

Output expected:

1.0/5.0 *****

2.0/4.0 ****

3.0/10.0 **********

Which part could be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readTextFile(const char *filename, int bin[], int freq[], int *N);
void printHist(const float bin[], const float freq[], int N);
void plotHorizontalHist(const float bin[], const float freq[], int N);
void plotVerticalHist(const float bin[], const float freq[], int N);



void printHist(const float bin[], const float freq[], int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {                  //Verify the data
        printf("%.1f %.1f\n", bin[i], freq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void plotHorizontalHist(const float bin[], const float freq[], int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%.1f/%.2f: ", bin[i],freq[i]);

        // Print '*' for each unit of frequency
        for (int j = 0; j < freq[i]; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void plotVerticalHist(const float bin[], const float freq[], int N) {
    // Find the maximum frequency to scale the vertical bars
    float maxFreq = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (freq[i] > maxFreq) {
            maxFreq = freq[i];
        }
    }

    // Print the vertical histogram
    for (int row = maxFreq; row > 0; row--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (freq[i] >= row) {
                printf("* ");
            } else {
                printf("  ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Print bin labels at the bottom
    printf("%.0f", bin[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {

        printf("%2.0f",bin[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}




void readTextFile(const char *filename, int bin[], int freq[], int *N) {
    FILE *f;
    char word[100];

    if ((f = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) {
        while (fscanf(f, "%s", word) == 1 && *N < 100) {
            int len = strlen(word);

            // Search for the length in the existing bins
            int found = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < *N; i++) {
                if (bin[i] == len) {
                    freq[i]++;
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If the length is not found, create a new bin
            if (!found) {
                bin[*N] = len;
                freq[*N] = 1;
                (*N)++;
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
    } else {
        printf("The file doesn't exist\n");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float bin[100];
    float freq[100];
    int N = 0;
    if (argc > 1) {

        readTextFile(filename,bin,freq,&N); 
        printHist(bin,freq,N);
        plotHorizontalHist(bin,freq,N);
        plotVerticalHist(bin,freq,N);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: insted of `printf("The file doesn't exist\n");` use `perror(filename)`;

Answer (score 1):

Your function is defined as taking `int` arrays, but they are defined as `float` arrays

```
void readTextFile(const char *filename, int bin[], int freq[], int *N);

    float bin[100];
    float freq[100];
```

Turn on your compiler warnings and **MIND THE WARNINGS!**

Comment: Thanks, that was my bad. I was thinking that I can just use int since all values are integer, cus the another part of program works on float.